# Windows balloon widget?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to have a balloon looking like this one in [Microsoft Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742400.aspx):

[image: Balloon Screenshot]

I have found this widget in `wx.lib.agw` called `BalloonTip`, but it looks... not native at least.

[image: agw Balloon screenshot]

Is there any good balloon widget in wxPython? I need it to look native on Windows and to look well on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [wxRichToolTip](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_rich_tool_tip.html) / [wx.adv.RichToolTip](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.adv.RichToolTip.html)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!